# Multi thread to process data and realtime display, thread and lock design in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, locking, threadpool

There is data to be displayed to user and function to process them. Each time the user interacts with the data, the function must be run on all the data and the result is displayed to the user. This should work multithreaded so there is no user interaction lag when function takes long time to process.

Now, I have 2 threads sharing `List`, first is running opengl loop at 60fps displaying content of `List` (not changing only reading). Second is sleeping, and when the user interacts with data it wakes up, runs function and writes result to `List` by assignment operation. The second thread breaks the function and restarts if user interacts before the function finishes. Here is the implementation:

```
class RestartableThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, input, output_list):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.output = output_list
        self.input = input
        self._restart = threading.Event()
        self._paused = threading.Event()
        self._state = threading.Condition()

    def restart(self, input):
        with self._state:
            self.input = input    # get new input
            self._restart.set()
            self._paused.clear()
            self._state.notify()  # unblock self if in paused mode

    def run(self):
        while True:
            with self._state:
                if self._paused.is_set():
                    self._state.wait() # wait until notify() - the thread is paused

            self._restart.clear()
            self.function()

    def function(self):
        # start empty
        result = []
        for elem in self.input:
            # end if restarted
            if self._restart.is_set():
                return
            # do something with elem that takes time
            result.append(elem)
        # done
        self.output = result
        # enter sleep
        with self._state:
             self._paused.set()  # enter sleep mode
        return
```

This works nice except that the fps of first thread's opengl loop is nicely 60 but when user interacts it drops to 20 for the time thread 2 works. Is it because second thread works with `List` and thread 1 cannot read from it efficiently? There are no thread locks on it. I tried..

```
# done
self.output = result.copy()
```

..so the function only works on copy of the list but same fps drop behavior. What is the best implementation of this (Queues maybe)?